# crete history record only when it change specific fields using django-simple-history

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I want to use django-simple-history for store history in database, but thing is i want to store history only defined specific field change, not when other field change. i didn't found any specific things for this. it has option for execlude_fields, but it won't helpful because it just ignore those fields from history.

Is there any suggestion?